# Using MYSQLI to populate dropdown box - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hey guys I am having some issues populating a drop down box using MYSQLI.
The code I have so far is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
include_once './includes/checkperm.php';
$permlevel = check_perm($_SESSION['myusername']);
if ($permlevel < "90" ) {
    header("location:permtolow.php");
    exit;
}
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../dbcon.php');
?>

<div class="label">Select Name:</div>
<select name="names">
<option value = "">---Select---</option>

<?php
$queryusers = "SELECT username FROM finance";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<option value='{".$d['username']."}'>".$d['username']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>'
?>
```

Unfortunately the drop down box stays empty.
I am probably missing something simple.

Comment: `echo "<option value='{".$d['username']."}'></option>";` the value here would look like `{Hampkade}` (you add `{}` around it). But you don't actually output anything to the option, should be something between`<option>HERE</option>` - if this doesn't answer what you're looking for, you need to enable error-reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Not <option value=test></option> but <option value=test>test</option>. Check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was when I called the require to the database connection:
Here is the fixed script, moving the "require" to the second PHP block.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}
include_once './includes/checkperm.php';
$permlevel = check_perm($_SESSION['myusername']);
if ($permlevel < "90" ) {
    header("location:permtolow.php");
    exit;
}
?>


<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../dbcon.php');
$queryusers = "SELECT * FROM finance";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $queryusers) or die (mysqli_error());
echo '<div class="label">Select Name:</div>';
echo '<select username="username">';
echo '<option value = "">---Select---</option>';
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<option value='{".$d['username']."}'>".$d['username']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is following.
If you simplify it to a bare minimum

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/php
  2 <?php
  3 $ar=array('one','two','three');
  4 foreach ($ar as $val){
  5 echo "<option value='{".$val."}'></option>";
  6 printf("\n");
  7 }
  8 ?>
```

And run it - you will end up with

```
[root@sshbuild ~]# ./phptest.php
<option value='{one}'></option>
<option value='{two}'></option>
<option value='{three}'></option>
```

See the problem?
You are missing values in between tags
Output should be like this

```
[root@sshbuild ~]# ./phptest.php
<option value='{one}'>one</option>
<option value='{two}'>two</option>
<option value='{three}'>three</option>
```

So what you need to do is this

```
echo "<option value='{".$d['username']."}'>".$d['username']."</option>";
```

Comment: I have adjusted the code but unfortunately the drop down box is still emtpy.

Comment: clean your browser cache. GETs are cached. Also you can activate developer mode in browser and post server response so we can see what your browser is actually receiving.

Comment: This is the response from the server:
`<div class="label">Select Name:</div>
<select username="username">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
</select>`

Comment: What's in your mysqli table? In other words think what output you should receive and think why you are not receiving it. Try to work from simple to more complex. What I would do - first make sure that your mysqli code works and fetches values that you expect. Once this works - move on to outputting values.

Comment: Basically from the server output that you posted it's clear that you are not fetching data from mysqli. Another issue was that you didn't output actual values, but that part of your code is not even triggered yet.

Comment: The sql code works when I input it directly into mysql, it just doesn't seem to get anything when I run it via PHP, could it be an issue with my configs?

Comment: It's impossible to say from information provided. Like I said - go from simple to more complex. Step 1. Make sure that your dbcon.php actually makes connection to database. You can add some debug code around it http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php Once sure that connection made - increase code complexity.

Comment: I have rebuilt the script from scratch and the issue seems to be that mysqli_query doesn't hold the retrieved data. I can see the connection to the server and that the query runs successfully, but mysqli_query outputs nothing.